# How to retrieve a MemoryTarget Logs property in a thread-safe manner in NLog while it is being written to

Tags: c#, logging, nlog, .net-4.8

I'm using a MemoryTarget Logger in my code which will be fed from another thread.

From time to time, I need to provide the logs to some webapi calls, so I need to retrieve the content of the Logs property.

The problem is, the Logs property is an IList backed by a List. So while writing to the log remain thread safe through NLog's help. I can't access the content of the logs while they are being writen to, and I cannot control when or where people are writting to the logs and there doesn't seem to be a thread safe option to retrieve the data.

I'm using the .Net 4.8 Framework.

The current simplified code

```cs
public const string filter = "theFilterHere";

public string TargetName { get; set; }

public MemoryTarget Logger { get; private set; }

public void InitLog() {
  Logger = new MemoryTarget();
  var rule = new LoggingRule(filter, LogLevel.Debug, Logger);
                    LogManager.Configuration.AddTarget(TargetName, Logger);
                    LogManager.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add(rule);
                    LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
}

public List<string> Logs { 
  // Crash happens here. I need the list in reverse order because reasons, but looking at it I know I would have the same problem if I did a ToList first.
  return Logger.Logs.Reverse().ToList();
}
```

I know using the SyncRoot of Logs won't help because I do not lock write access to the logs. The only idea I have today is casting the Logs (IList) as a List, then doing a code similar to :

```cs
List<string> currentLogs = Logger.Logs as List<string>;
if (currentLogs is null) {
  // NLog changed the internal structure of MemoryTarget.
  return Logger.Logs.Reverse().ToList();
}
int count = currentLogs.Count;
string[] logs = new string[count];

// Assumption : the list doesn't shrink, the log will only grow and never empty.
// this is only available on List<T>, and internally seems to do an Array copy of the _items array.
currentLogs.CopyTo(0, logs, 0, count);
```

Am I on the right track or am I hopelessly wrong ?

Comment: Created https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/5409 to make the Logs-property thread-safe with upcoming NLog ver. 5.2.6

Comment: @RolfKristensen I never expected such a quick response especially from a contributor. You sir are the GOAT. I went ahead and made my own LayoutTarget backed by a ConcurrentStack while waiting for the next version. I don’t need everything an IList can do like prune or modify the log list, plus I needed to reverse the list so one bird two stone. But thanks a ton for the quick response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NLog v5.2.6 has been released that allows thread-safe enumeration of the NLog [MemoryTarget](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Memory-target) `Logs`-property:

- https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog/5.2.6

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/pull/5409